# Odd Behavior with a Wrapping Flexbox and Scrolling Child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I recently ran into this issue when playing around with layouts and it has completely stumped me.

I was making a sidebar with flex box.

```css
.sidebar-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 20rem;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 2rem;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 999;
  min-width: 50%;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <div class="sidebar">Sidebar content here.</div>
      <div class="content">I am some content that should always take up 50%. I might have more content, but it shouldn't matter.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And it has the wrapping behavior I expected (once the viewport is contracted):

[image: the wrapper behavior I wanted]

I then thought it would be cool to add some content in a gallery that the user could scroll. Simple.

[image: content with scrolling]

But this doesn't do what I would expect, the content doesn't wrap anymore. I checked with inspect element and **both** examples had the same width!

```css
.sidebar-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 20rem;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 2rem;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 999;
  min-width: 50%;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.scrolling-content {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.scrolling-content > * {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <div class="sidebar">Sidebar content here.</div>
      <div class="content">I am some content that should always take up 50%. I might have more content, but it shouldn't matter.
      <div class="scrolling-content">
        <div>
          one of many children
        </div>
        <div>
          one of many children
        </div>
        <div>
          one of many children
        </div>
        <div>
          one of many children
        </div>
        <div>
          one of many children
        </div>
        <div>
          one of many children
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? I would expect the wrapping behavior to still work around the parent being less than `50%` of the content and not to include the overflowed elements. The only solution I found that works so far is using `position: absolute` on the scrolling div and using padding to make space for it (but that's super hacky and doesn't work well for content that could be various heights).

Comment: Works as expected in both chrome and firefox, You're just not hitting the window width yet for elements to stack below each other.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I'm just confused why it isn't using the original width of the parent (and how can this behavior be worked around).

Comment: It only works when the window is big enough to display all of the scroll elements before the window is resized. If any overflow happens initially - then it breaks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, the  code works exactly the same in both cases

Comment: Add more scrolled elements and keep the window small on the first draw (too small to display all the "hello"s) - the behavior will not be the same then.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet on jsfiddle or codepen ?